# Do some ajax using jquery in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm able to do very basic jquery ajax in asp.net. But I'm stuck at a point. Please see the below image.[image]

As this dialog has a file Upload control, I'm not able to figure it out how to post the data to server and do proper operation. I'm even confused How will I get the file on the server side.
In normal cases (postback one) we can access the posted file useing

```
FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream
```

But when I'm intending it to do using a `[WebMethod]` I'm not able to findout how to do this.
Please help me with some sample or any link to tutorial.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JavaScript alone then you can only do it with conjunction with HTML5 (or rather XMLHttpRequest2). Namely using the [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object which isn't supported by all browsers (see link for list of compatible browsers). That's why all the fancy uploader controls require either HTML5 or Flash, SilverLight or other browser add-ons.

The Mozilla developer network has [this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) on how to send a file using JavaScript.

Comment: :: I'm using jquery-1.8.2.js. And I really want it to support IE7+

Comment: @KrishanuDey - Then I'm afraid you're out of luck and stuck doing it the old way or using Flash/SilverLight

Answer (score 0):

Here is file uploading code

```
  <form action="/home/save" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
      Upload Image: <input type="file" name="image" />
     <input type="submit" value="upload" /> </form>'
```

And server side code is as follow

```
for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[i];
            file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(@"~\Files\" + file.FileName));
        }
```